# Is it possible to use the facebook API on XAMPP (local server)?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xampp, facebook-php-sdk

Is it possible to use the facebook api like we do it on sites live on the internet , but on XAMPP ( a local server) installed on my computer ?  I'd really appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly the API's should work fine unless you have a registered domain associated with the API app key.

You have not specified which API you are using [Facebook has a lot of API's with various security levels]

A few disadvantages on working on local machines are as follows

1. A local machine is identified as an anonymous request coming from some IP as its not associated with a domain. Therefore chances of blocking your API request are high.
2. Your system may have imposed firewall rules for incoming and outgoing requests, if your local server is not configured to send and receive outbound requests your might be in trouble.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is sent from a mobile, don't ask me how but the comment system doesn't work nicely for me.

A local server is the same as a live website, the only difference is that you run it locally...

If you have an internet connection while running the server, you're basicly the same as every other server....
but well if you don't have internet on it don't expect it to be working....
[but ofcourse you can only connect to it locally and not from other computers xD]

I hope I answered your question now, Feel free to add a comment if you want to.

Yours sincerely,
Mike M.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just make sure that redirect url must be the url which we put in the facebook while building the app.